# Website notifications

Tags: javascript, backend, mbaas

I have a web app that has native mobile versions. the app involves messaging that has been implemented. I can send and receive the messages no problem and the notifications are working on android. But i need to be able to notify the web user when a new message is there to be read.
The back-end services is provided by Telerik and there are javascript functions fired when there is new content. the web app is built primary in javascript as well. how do i pass a message from the JS running on the back-end and the front-end web app.

Comment: through an async communication method? socket.io ?

Comment: yoy can do that using service workers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how it could be done through Telerik, but typically a backend would establish a websocket to send async notifications to clients, in this particular case to web app. A communication to a websocket could be done for native android app as well (instead of push notifications service by Google).